# How to add color in highmap highchart based on value

Tags: highcharts

Here is my highmap based on highchart plugin,I want to add color in each area based on value,for example if value is between 0 to 100, color will be green again if value is between 100 to 200 color will be blue again if value is between 200 to 300 color will be yellow again if value is between 300 to 400 color will be red.
Below is my html code

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>

$.getJSON('http://localhost/highcharts/highmaps/sample.json', function (data) {

    // Make codes uppercase to match the map data
    $.each(data, function () {
        this.code = this.code.toUpperCase();
    });

    // Instantiate the map
    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

        chart: {
            map: 'countries/us/us-all',
            borderWidth: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'US population density (/km²)'
        },

        exporting: {
            sourceWidth: 600,
            sourceHeight: 500
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true
        },



        series: [{
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            },
            data: data,
            joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                format: '{point.code}'
            },
            name: 'Population density',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.value}/km²'
            }
        }]
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Sample.json

```
[
    {
        "value": 438,
        "code": "nj"


    },
    {
        "value": 387.35,
        "code": "ri",
        "color":"blue"
    },
    {
        "value": 312.68,
        "code": "ma"

    },
    {
        "value": 271.4,
        "code": "ct"

    },
    {
        "value": 209.23,
        "code": "md"

    },
    {
        "value": 195.18,
        "code": "ny"

    },
    {
        "value": 154.87,
        "code": "de"

    },
    {
        "value": 114.43,
        "code": "fl"

    },
    {
        "value": 107.05,
        "code": "oh"

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer,

Just we need to add in script

```
     Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: ''
  }
});
     colorAxis: {
                        dataClasses: [{
                            to: 500,
                            color: "green"
                        }, {
                            from: 500,
                            to: 1000,
                            color: "blue"
                        }, {
                            from: 1000,
                            to: 2500,
                            color: "yellow"
                        }, {
                            from: 2500,
                            to: 5000,
                            color: "red"
                        }]
                    },
```